# How to execute a command in bash ,where the bash is created using exec() command in C

Tags: c, linux, bash, process, fork

If I want to execute to ls command in a bash which I have created using the way

```
if(fork() == 0)
{
    dup2(fileDescriptor,1); // redirecting standard output
    execlp("bash","bash","-l",NULL);
}
```

then how do I send the input ls to the newly created bash ?

Comment: How about just invoking `bash -c yourcommand`

Comment: need to do in C code

Comment: `execlp("bash", "bash", "-c", "somecommand", NULL);` is C.

Comment: The other approach is to set up a FIFO and feed your script on the new process's stdin, but that's a *bad* approach -- you can't reliably distinguish the output boundaries between different commands run in that shell, you lose exit status information for individual commands, etc. There's a reason it isn't conventional to use noninteractively.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy thanks a lot !. The first suggestion worked.

Comment: Also, do you actually need a shell? If you're just running a single command and don't need the features it provides (wildcard expansion, I/O redirection, etc) you can just run `ls` directly with `execlp("ls", "ls", NULL);`

Comment: @GordonDavisson the problem I asked is a small part of a bigger problem I was trying to solve.